# What is RCE protocol?

Tags: omap

I tried to search online but there is not direct resource introducing what is the RCE protocol.

I encountered this term while dealing with OMAP kernel flashing.

Anyone can explain to me or best if could paste me some useful link so that I could proceed with my research. Thanks

Comment: Do you have some context, such as a direct quote?

Comment: Does link useful to you or else I will delete the answer

Answer (score 0):

[RCE - Remote Chronos Entry](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/RCE_-_Remote_Chronos_Entry)

You can refer this TI document I will soon update answer for more